# mongodb client - ssh connection from localhost php

Tags: mongodb, database

I have been using rockmongo as my client for mongodb on localhost for testing.
For prodction i DONT want a client online as this might reduce security.
Is there a client which will allow me to connect `SSH`? kind of like **MySql Workbench**?
or
Can rockmongo stay on my local computer and i connect to EC2 instance which has mongodb for production viewing?
or
Is there a better alternative to all of this?
My setup is a standard `LAMP` stack.  willing to make any changes necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MongoHub](http://mongohub.todayclose.com/) has the option to connect over ssh, but the app kind of sucks. It crashes a lot.

A more generic approach would be to just create your own ssh tunnel to your production server, and then connect over that through whatever client you want. The client won't care as long as it can make the connection.

On OSX/Linux, creating an ssh tunnel might look like this:

```
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:27017 -f -C -q -N username@domain.com
```

This would open a local port `8080` which will forward the traffic to the localhost interface at the mongodb default port `27017` on the remote side. You would point your client at `127.0.0.1:8080` as if mongodb were running there locally.

Comment: will have to look into how this can be done `create your own ssh tunnel to your production server, and then connect over that through whatever client you want.`

Comment: What operating system are you on locally?

Comment: locally im on win7 but i can use osx or linux if i had too

Comment: here's the solution from win7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182552/ssh-tunnelier-rock-mongo-connect-to-ec2-from-win7

Answer (score 0):

Check some of these out - http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

One workaround would be to set that file in a separate folder and make a .htaccess file that restricts access to only your ip address.  Any requests not from your ip address would get denied access...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i'm looking to keep any admin stuff local